# Perform action after findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock completed in for loop

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, concurrency, parse-platform

I have such construction in my code:

```
for (METMeetingEntity *e in self.meetingList) {
            PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];        
            //some query constraints, depending on METMeetingEntity
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
            {
                // some query actions


                NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
                self.meetingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.meetingList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
                self.meetingList = [self dateCleanup:self.meetingList];
            }];
```

How can I perform action - reload my table view after all the `findObjectsInBackground` are completed

Comment: This code seems strange. You iterate some original `meetingList` array. And for each iteration of that original array, you create and assign a new array to the same property. Only the last iteration will end up being useful.

Comment: Missed your comment. This seemed strange as all the actions with sorting are meant to be excited in dispatch_async block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution would be to keep a count. When the number matches the original count, you know you are done.

```
NSUInteger count = self.meetingList.count;
for (METMeetingEntity *e in self.meetingList) {
    PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];        
    //some query constraints, depending on METMeetingEntity
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        // some query actions
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];
        self.meetingList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.meetingList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]];
        self.meetingList = [self dateCleanup:self.meetingList];

        count--;
        if (count == 0) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                // reload table or whatever needs to be done
            });
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: Yep, I that worked out. I was thinking initially about dispatch_async thing.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need calling dispatch_async. All the blocks in Parse run in the main thread. In Parse doc you can read:

> Both findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: and
>   findObjectsInBackgroundWithTarget:selector: work similarly in that
>   they assure the network request is done without blocking, and run the
>   block/callback in the main thread.

This is an example of a query for a UICollectionView:

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if(!error) {
            listaFiguras = [objects mutableCopy];
            [_collectionView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Something wrong. No Data.");
        }
    }];
```