# iOS label's text property not updating after a Parse query?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I have a Parse query which runs fine, and then I want to update the label's text value in the simulator with what the query returns. When I print the label's text value in the console, the correct value shows up. However, when I run the simulator, it appears to be null (or the label does not update). (side note: I set UI constraints for the label and am sure that the label is in place. I've tested that with static values).

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    __block PFObject *queriedObj;
    __block NSArray *queriedArray;

    self.finishedQuery = false;
    NSLog(@"view did load ID = %@", self.ID);

    if (self.ID) {

        // QUERY BEGINS
        PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Questions"];
        [query2 whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.ID];
        //queriedArray = [query2 findObjects];
        [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                queriedArray = objects;
                // queriedArray has 1 PFObject.

                for (PFObject *obj in queriedArray) {
                    queriedObj = obj;
                } // Grabs the PFObject
                // Grabs an Array of elements from the PFObject
                self.AnswersArray = [queriedObj objectForKey:@"Answers"];

                // Test to confirm array not null
                NSLog(@"array elts: %lu", (unsigned long)[self.AnswersArray count]);


                if ([self.AnswersArray count] == 1) { // if one item in array, only show 0th index

                    self.labelString = [self.AnswersArray objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSLog(@"label string: %@", self.labelString);

                    //self.AnswersText.text = self.labelString;

                    NSLog(@"answerstext: %@", self.AnswersText.text);
                }
                if ([self.AnswersArray count] != 0 && [self.AnswersArray count] != 1) {
                    [self generateRandomInt];
                    NSLog(@"random: %d", self.randomInt);

                    self.labelString = [self.AnswersArray objectAtIndex:self.randomInt]; // displays a random answer
                    self.AnswersText.text = self.labelString;
                }

                NSLog(@"final answers text: %@", self.AnswersText.text);

            }
        }];
    } 
}
```

Essentially, the label's value (self.AnswersText.text) is printing correctly in the console. However, it is not changing in the simulator. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What does the log show if you print the self.labelString immediately after the self.labelString assignment, like you did in the case of 1 item?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing this operation in the background.

[UI things need to happen on the main thread / main queue](http://www.acnenomor.com/956375p1/findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-gets-data-from-parse-but-data-only-exists-inside-the-block).

Try doing:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    self.AnswersText.text = self.labelString;
});
```

This same technique can be seen [in this related question I just found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24999986/perform-action-after-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock-completed-in-for-loop).

Comment: @PeterSmith I've actually tried that, but when I test it, it changes the correct value in the console to null and nothing changes in the simulator. Do you know why?

Comment: I don't think the OP is doing the operation in the background. I'm pretty sure that the completion block of findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: runs on the main thread.

Comment: I don't think this is a thread problem either. See my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of background thread vs main thread, findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock: calls its completion block on the main thread.

The problem, I think, comes from `[self.AnswersArray objectAtIndex:self.randomInt]`
I don't know how you generate your random int, but it is most probable that it is bigger than the size of your array. As a result you must have an exception thrown when you call `objectAtIndex:`.

The problem is that since Parse uses the Bolts framework, exceptions thrown in completion blocks are automatically caught and silently ignored (very annoying, I know). You can check by adding an "All Exceptions" breakpoint. Go to the breakpoints tab in the left panel of Xcode, and at the bottom left clic : + -> Add Exception Breakpoint.

Also, if you want to avoid exceptions being caught, you can wrap your completion block this way :

```
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Your logic here
    });
}];
```

If you want a random index in your array, I suggest you use :

```
u_int32_t randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)self.AnswersArray.count);
```

And make sure that `self.AnswersArray.count` is not 0 before.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering - but that really can't be the problem, because i do check my array's bounds in that function, and the text value does print out correctly. It just doesn't update the Label's text field. Is there anything else you could suggest?

Comment: Update: I re-checked that the random number was 2 and there are 4 elements in the array. Also, after adding the wrap in my completion block, it resulted in a null text value, rather than the correctly printing value in the simulator. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I got it wrong. It looks like your variable is being set properly in viewDidLoad, but reset to nil before the view is displayed. Can you check in other methods that are called after viewDidLoad that you don't set self.AnswersText.text to nil ? Mainly in viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Comment: I checked that, no luck :/ Can I send you the file? My other methods don't do much, but maybe you'll be able to see something i've missed!

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer and add a link to a gist (https://gist.github.com), that way everyone can help you.