# Calling dispatch_get_main_queue() not needed with Parse SDK right?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, parse-server

I'm using the Parser Server SDK for iOS apps and it seems like the returning block in the following method is always on main thread  (even though, yes, it's running in background when the data is fetching):

```
- (void)findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:(nullable PFQueryArrayResultBlock)block;
```

So therefore it seems unnecessary to use this common GCD method before updating the UI, so I removed it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // reload table or whatever
});
```

But I haven't seen anything about it in the documentation, though. Does anyone know   if it's totally safe to just ignore GCD when using Parse SDK fetching methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, apparently the answer is: yes! The block code in `PFQuery`-methods always runs on the main thread and there is no need to return to main before updating the UI.

I found it in the docs, and also in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29030650/3776782) here at Stack Overflow.

(However, if you take advantage of a `BFTask`-method from the `Bolts.framework`, linked to the SDK, the answer is no!)